# Hide command line arguments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to hide these command line arguments (the blue texts) when I run or debug code, so that I can see the result more clearly. Does anyone know?

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: is this the Code Runner extension?

Comment: you are able to run/debug, it would be a bigger problem if not, that is how VSC works, if you know a shorter command let the Java extension repo know